# Using COM objects in MetroStyle apps

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

Is it possible to use COM objects in MetroStyle apps? I wanted to develop a simple app that uses MediaMonkey's API through COM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general it is not possible to use existing COM objects from a metro style application.  There are some exceptions, but almost all existing COM objects will be blocked at runtime.

Your best bet is to see if the MediaMonkey folks can repackage their API as a winrt component and then add that component to your package.

Comment: Thanks .And if not, what do you think is my best solution? Maybe creating a .Net app that uses COM object and running it via command-line?

Comment: CoCreateInstance is blocked from Metro style apps (it's not in the metro partition of the windows 8 sdk).  CoCreateInstanceFromApp blocks all but a small set of CLSIDs when called from a metro style application.  So there really isn't a way of doing what you want.